# AWS upload to S3 with SQS - PHP syntax

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Would uploading to S3 using SQS make the process more fault tolerant?

If so, i am having a hard time with syntax, trying to combine creating a `queue` then uploading to S3.
If my logic is not correct, how would i set up a system using `SQS` to upload to `S3`?

```
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

// *these keys are random strings
$AWS_KEY = "6VVWTU4JDAAKHYB1C3ZN";
$AWS_SECRET_KEY = "GMSCUD8C0QA1QLV9Y3RP2IAKDIZSCHRGKEJSXZ4F";

//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', $AWS_KEY);
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', $AWS_SECRET_KEY);
//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

//check whether a form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    //retreive post variables
    $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];

    //create a new bucket
    $s3->putBucket("mybucket", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);




    //add the queue
    $sqs = new AmazonSQS(array( "key" => $AWS_KEY, "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY ));
    $response = $sqs->create_queue('test-topic-queue');
    $queue_url = (string) $response->body->CreateQueueResult->QueueUrl;
    $queue_arn = 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic-queue';

    //$queue_url . ?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Your%20Message%20Text?&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Version=2011-10-01?&Expires=2008-02-10T12:00:00Z?&Signature=lBP67vCvGlDMBQ1do?fZxg8E8SUEXAMPLE&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256


    // HOW DO I INCORPORATE SQS AND S3



    //move the file
    if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, 
                                "mybucket", 
                                "myFolder/" . $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, 
                                array(), 
                                $_FILES['theFile']['type']) ) {
        //it works
    }else{
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to incorporate? SQS is for messaging, while S3 is for object storage. You can't use SQS to make the actual upload to S3 more fault tolerant. But maybe I am missing your question?

Comment: Secondly I hope that it is not your actual AWS credentials you have posted in the code snippet. If so you need to go revoke them.

Comment: @oens you didnt catch the sentence *these keys are random strings.  i read that sqs can be placed inbetween process, this is the part i wasnt sure about when uploading to S3

Comment: Yes SQS can be used to manage messaging between components. What you are basically doing above is uploading an object(in this case a file) to S3 and in this specific process of _uploading_ the file there is no idea in using SQS(unless you split the file in chunks and store them in the message queue, but come on what would be the purpose of that?). You perform the upload directly to S3 without using SQS. SQS is useful if for example you wanted to do some processing when a new file was uploaded. Then you could add an entry to SQS upon upload to do backend processing of the newly uploaded file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly understanding the fault tolerance you are requesting. But in terms of using S3 and SQS for scaling, there is an excellent paper on the Amazon AWS website that talks about scaling up and down your infrastructure using SQS and EC2 together, which can of course include processes like uploading to S3 and using SQS to tell the application to process something. You don't mention whether or not you're using EC2 or if this is of interest.

Here is the article: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1464

Otherwise, it sounds like your logic may be confused as SQS isn't an in-between from server to S3, but rather more for application messaging.

Comment: im understanding the concept from the diagram, just having difficulties putting it into practical code

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured out the OP's confusion on this topic.

The diagram shown makes it appear that SQS is handling uploads, but its really not, when you upload 1 or 100 photo's, they're added to S3 directly, then using SQS it creates a "Task" which one of the EC2 "Processing Servces" will pull, and then grab the actual picture from the S3 storage that as named in the SQS message.

Hopefully this gives some insight for future users who see this question feeling lost.