# AWS SQS practical code PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

i had a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085573/aws-upload-to-s3-with-sqs-php-syntax)
but i'm still missing the point understanding how to use SQS,  could anyone help out with some code please.
**question:** what would one place inside a SQS?
i've read through amazons tutorial and the concept seems lovely but im missing the practical side of things.

for instance, this diagram is great: http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/catalog/images/159-for-madhu.png
what would go inside the SQS?  I understand how to upload to S3, but still grey about the SQS part

```
require_once('sdk-1.5.6.2/sdk.class.php');
//random strings
$AWS_KEY = "MY_ACCESS_KEY";
$AWS_SECRET_KEY = "MY_SECRET_KEY";


//create a new SQS queue and grab the queue URL
$sqs = new AmazonSQS(array( "key" => $AWS_KEY, "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY ));
$response = $sqs->create_queue('test-topic-queue');
$queue_url = (string) $response->body->CreateQueueResult->QueueUrl;

$queue_arn = 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic-queue';
$topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic';
$response = $sns->subscribe($topic_arn, 'sqs', $queue_arn);
$subscription_arn = (string) $response->body->SubscribeResult->SubscriptionArn;




/*  *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *     

THIS IS THE BIG GREY AREA, WHAT HAPPENS HERE ??? 

*   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */



// delete SQS queue
$queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ENCQ8gqrAcXv/test-topic-queue'; 
$response = $sqs->delete_queue($queue_url);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should have two processes, one that inserts messages into the queue and your worker threads. A typical worker thread will look something like this:

```
while(true) {
    $res = $client->receiveMessage(array(
        'QueueUrl'          => $url,
        'WaitTimeSeconds'   => 1
    ));
    if ($res->getPath('Messages')) {

        foreach ($res->getPath('Messages') as $msg) {
            echo "Received Msg: ".$msg['Body'];

            // Do something useful with $msg['Body'] here

            $res = $client->deleteMessage(array(
                'QueueUrl'      => $url,
                'ReceiptHandle' => $msg['ReceiptHandle']
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

The WaitTimeSeconds parameters means to do "long polling" and has various benefits (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html).

You should use supervise or monit to make sure your worker threads stay running.

UPDATE: for api v3 use get() instead of getPath() - getPath is now deprecated

Comment: Instead of doing `while(true)` which will eventually eat all server resources, AWS allows you to use Worker Tier in Elastic Beanstalk that has an SQS daemon which automatically retrieves the messages from the queue and posts them to your app. More info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: @ABC "`while(true)` which will eventually eat all server resources"   Why would it eventually eat all server resources unless there's a bug (eg memory leak)?

Comment: @JoshJohnson as far as remember my program at the time was not properly garbage collected, so I think you're right - there was a memory leak.

Answer (score 10):

No code.. but an example (explaining the diagram basically).

You have a website where people can upload video. You want to convert every video to .mp4 (or .flv if you're that kinda guy).

Transcoding takes (for the sake of the argument) 1 minute per video. You don't want to do this in the same HTTP / PHP request as the upload, as it will take 1 minute for the video to return, and it means that many videos may be transcoding on the webserver on any given moment.

What you need instead, are separate machines / instances 100% responsible for transcoding. They get 'jobs' and process them in order (a queue). We call them workers.

So how are you going to communicate from your webserver that a worker should start trancoding. 1 way would be to set a database record that the workers check every x seconds.

This is not a great design. Generally whenever you must resort to polling, you're developing a workaround for something that can be more efficient.

In the PHP world, one way to do this is with Gearman. Alternatively, a ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, but Gearman is quite the popular PHP solution. In the AWS world they provide SQS. Responsible for one thing:

Pushing in messages on 1 end. In this example these are the jobs coming from the webserver.
Waiting for new messages on the other end. In this example these are the workers waiting for stuff to do.

The nice thing about SQS is that you can just add workers on 1 end, and add webservers on the other end. SQS makes sure only 1 worker gets the message. So it meets the horizontal scaling paradigm (provided SQS itself scales horizontally).

Comment: "how are you going to communicate from your webserver that a worker should start trancoding" - do you suggest setting up a cron on the processing instance that checks for queue's?

Comment: Hi! No.. that would defeat the purpose. Just have long-running PHP processes that wait for a message.

Comment: curious how to do that! this subject is exponentially creating more questions

Comment: Hi! It may be better to start with a use-case, and then figure out how to do it. So start a new question and ask how you can achieve what you want to do.

Comment: It looks like you can set up a long-running process via SQS Long Polling (although "long-running" means "up to 20 seconds" here): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html

Comment: @Evert: Your statement that "SQS makes sure only 1 worker gets the message" is not true. SQS makes sure *at least* one worker gets the message. In your example the transcoding action would exceed the default visibility timeout and is very likely to be run more than once.

Comment: @Evert, Do you really need to use polling if you can't have SQS?

Comment: @Pacerier what is your alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking, what is the purpose of having the SQS as per the given image. I will give a high level idea on how the SQS can be used according to this [image](http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/catalog/images/159-for-madhu.png), you have mentioned in the question.

SQS is simply a buffer that is used by processes, to handle the load they get because some processes can be overwhelmed when multiple requests are coming all at once. I'll explain the image step by step according to the given image. It seems like a photo processing server, where the user uploads a photo, and the user will get back a processed photo.

**Step 1**: The user uploads a photo to the `web-server`, and it gets stored in S3. In the mean time, the request is being sent to the `Request Queue` (which probably contains the location of the queue). This process happens to all the user requests.

**Step 2**: The `Photo processing server` will poll SQS and check for any incoming requests. Takes a request (which contains the location of the image on S3) and gets the image from S3 and processes it.

**Step 3**: The processed image will be stored in S3 by the `Photo Processing Server`, and its url will be sent to the `Response Queue`. The `Web Server` will poll the `Response Queue` and gives the download URL to the user. So the user can download the processed image from S3.

This is one possible use case of SQS in the image. According to your code, you really don't need an SNS. The Web Server can simply upload to S3, and S3 can publish the upload event in SQS. ([Read this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)). This can also be done with the response queue.

This is what happens in the gray area where SQS is being used for this task.